# Reusing subprocess object

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a Python script that needs to issue a number of shell commands.  I thought I could just create a subprocess object and then reuse it each time I had a command to execute.

This is how I have my code set up:

```
def setupPipeline(self):
    setupShell = subprocess.Popen([''], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    # Stop running pipeline
    setupShell.stdin.write('stop ' + self.Name)
    output = setupShell.stdout.read()
    print output

    # Cancel any running jobs and cleanup variables
    setupShell.stdin.write('sudo -u pr cancel ALL')
    output = setupShell.stdout.read()
    print output

    setupShell.stdin.write('sudo -u pr clean ALL')
    output = setupShell.stdout.read()
    print output
```

(skip a lot of other code here)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
#self-test code
pipelineObj = Pipeline(sys.argv)
pipelineObj.setupPipeline()
```

However, when the code gets to the second command I get a

```
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

How do I go about reusing a subprocess object to issue commands that need to all execute within the same shell?  These commands can't be simply chained together since there is processing going on in between each call.

Comment: (a) why must you re-use the same shell over and over? (b) why must you use a shell at all? You could simply [execute those commands directly using an array to split apart command from argument](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) -- and be confident that the `PATH` nor `IFS` environment variables will influence the execution of your program.

Comment: Because the results of each command need to affect the subsequent commands shell environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a subprocess that executes a shell, and send commands to that. You're running an empty command *in* the shell, which causes it to execute that empty command and then exit.

```
shell = subprocess.Popen("/bin/bash -i".split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

You might instead consider using [`pexpect`](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) as it sounds like you are well on your way to reinventing it.

Comment: I thought I was doing that with the "setupShell = " line. I thought if I didn't issue an initial command it would just create a shell process without exiting.

Comment: No, look at what command you are executing in that line: `''`. `shell=True` means that the empty command will be executed in the shell, but what will keep the shell running after the empty command is executed? Nothing, that's what.